# How to change the background image in button control template in wpf

Tags: wpf, imagebutton, controltemplate, wpf-4.0

I wanted to change the background image on mouse over. But i could n't. below is my source code..

```
    <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
          <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Source="../Resources/Images/refresh.png"   Width="16" Height="16" />
           </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
```

I tried with below code but it is not even compiling..

```
       <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Resources/Images/refresh_Hover.png"                            />
           </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Any help ?

Comment: Apart from what nit suggested. You can also use two images and just play with the visibility in trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to give `x:Name` to `Image`  and in setter set `TargetName` to the image name given. It should work.